# Comprobar conexión a base de datos MySQL con PHP - PDO

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

Tengo en mi sitio una base de datos con los usuarios y sus contraseñas para poder ingresar a la página. La base de datos está bien, lo mismo la página de logeo, funcionaban bien sin problema. Hasta hace unos días, sin razón aparente, dejó de funcionar. Este es el código que utilizaba para conectarme:

```
<?php

class conexion {

  public static function conectar ()
  {
    try {

      $cn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=misitio_bdatos","miusuario","qaz123");

      return $cn;

    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
      die($ex->getMessage() );
    }

  }

}    //sin etiqueta de cierre por ser parte de un require
```

Entonces decidí comprobar si realmente esos datos estaban bien, con el siguiente código que encontré en internet y nombré como comprobar.php

```
<?php
    function Conectarse()
    {
    $host='localhost:3306';
    $usuariodb='miusuario';
    $passwdb='qaz123';
    $nombredb='misitio_bdatos';

    if (!($link=mysql_connect($host,$usuariodb,$passwdb)))
    {
    echo "Error conectando a la base de datos.";
    exit();
    }
    if (!mysql_select_db($nombredb,$link))
    {
    echo "Error seleccionando la base de datos, verifique que el nombre de usuario utilizado este asociado a la base de datos.";
    exit();
    }
    return $link;
    }

    $link=Conectarse();
    echo "Conexión con la base de datos conseguida.
    ";
    mysql_close($link); //cierra la conexion
    ?>
```

Pero cuando voy a ese archivo en misitio.com/comprobar.php me muestra el mensaje

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

¿Cómo puedo comprobar que realmente esta conexión se esté haciendo de forma correcta?

Estoy trabajando con PDO para validar los inicios de sesión.

Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas trabajando con PDO puede probar esta conexión

```php
<?php
   class conexion {
      private $host = "nombre HOST";
      private $user = "usuario";
      private $pass = "password";
      private $database = "nombre de la base de datos";

      //database handler
      private $dbh;
      //statement
      private $stmt;
      //errores
      private $error;

      public static function conectar() {
         //configurar la conexión
         $dsn = "mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->database;
         //opciones que se agregaran a la conexion mysql
         //PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT - la conexion con pdo será persistente, optimizara los recursos del servidor

         $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE =>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
         );

         //creamos una instancia de PDO
         //lo insertamos en una excepcion
         try{

            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn,$this->user,$this->pass,$options);
            //con la siguiente instrucción controlamos el return de caracteres extraños que no puede interpretar la db
            $this->dbh->exec('set names '.UTF8);
            echo "Conexion realizada con exito";
         }catch(PDOException $e){
             $this->error = $e->getMessage();
             echo "Excepcion: ".$this->error;
         }
      } 
   }

?>
```

Comment: estimafo αλρθα traté de responderle en base al primer código que esta orientado a objetos donde la clase se llama conexion y el método conectar(), de ahi usé el código que yo ocupo con pdo para hacer conexiones con mysql en mis proyectos, saludos.

Comment: Si me equivoqué y cuando revisé por eso te di +1

Comment: Gracias Kevin, me sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje :( `The resource you are looking for has been removed (...)` Puede ser un tema de hosting? Aclaro que en la línea 6 probé tanto con comillas sin comillas para DB_DATABASE

Comment: Saludo LauraZ ¿has cambiado nombre de algo? porque el mensaje dice **El recurso que buscas ha sido eliminado** o ya te aseguraste de que las credenciales esten correcto. Una pregunta ¿tienes la db en localhost o tienes un hosting que te proporcione la db?

Comment: Perdón la demora en responder. Tengo la BD en un hosting, no he cambiado nada de tu código (a excepción de los datos de acceso obviamente), ya cambié la contraseña, cambié el usuario, eliminé y volví a subir la BD. Como menciono en mi pregunta, dejó de funcionar de un momento para otro.